# Triangle similarity question

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image: question]

I've been trying to solve this question for like 40 mins straight and can't seem to get anywhere. I tried drawing a parallel to |KM| from C to |AB| but that didn't seem to help. I just can't see a way to get to |MN|.

Comment: Do you know anything about $\triangle ABC$? It looks like an equilateral triangle in the diagram.

Comment: Nothing is given

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Menelaus' theorem, (AB)(KN)(MC)/(BK)(NM)(CA) = 1 (using unsigned lengths)
Similarly, (AM)(CN)(BK)/(MC)(NB)(KA) = 1.

Using the second equation, AM/MC = 6 and hence AC/MC = 5. Substituting into the first equation, we find KN/NM = 5/3. Together with MK = 24, we get MN = 9.

Comment: Its |KN| that intersects the ABC triangle and |BC| intersects AKM triangle right ?

Comment: Yes, more specifically KM is the transversal of the triangle ABC and vice versa.

Comment: Do you have an easy way of writing Menelaus I always have trouble choosing the right sides.

Comment: For writing Menelaus, the transversal will always cut the triangle at three sides, 1 of which is extended.

Comment: If you let DEF be transversal of ABC, with D on BC, E on CA, F on AB, menelaus would be (AE)(CD)(BF)/(EC)(DB)(FA) = 1. It doesn't really matter which side is extended, for easy memorization.

Answer (score 1):

Construction: (1) Join BM; (2) Let T be the midpoint of KA. Join TN; (3) Join AN.

[image]

From the construction, BK = KT = TA; and therefore, all yellow shaded (including light, normal and dirty) triagnles are equal in area.

In ⊿s ABN and ACN, because BN : NC = 3 : 1, all yellow shaded (including light, normal ,dirty AND orange) triangles are equal in area (= Y say).

In ⊿s MBN and MCN, because BN : NC = 3 : 1, area of the **R**ed-shaded : area of the **P**ink-shaded = 3 : 1. We will denote this result as $\frac {R}{P} = \frac {3}{1}$……….(1)

Similarly, in ⊿s MBK and MAK, we have  $\frac {Y + R}{3Y + P} = \frac {1}{2}$……….(1)

Eliminating P from (1) and (2), we have $\frac {Y}{R} = \frac {5}{3}$

This means $\frac {KN}{NM} = \frac {5}{3}$

Therefore, $NM = \frac {3}{5 + 3} × 24 = 9$